# Is there any law in the Unites States (in NYC) requiring plumbing inspections after ___ years in apartment buildings?

Tags: landlord, tenant, fair-housing-acts

I live in Brooklyn, NY and recently my apartment unit toilet had a minor clog and overflow (when I wasn’t home) that the landlord is insisting has caused water damage in his basement (I saw there was damage) and he wants me to pay for the fix. I hired a plumber and contractor to come (out of my own pocket), and they verified that I did not cause the damage.

I checked with the local building department and found out my building hasn’t had a plumbing inspection since 2003. Is this legal?

From doing some quick googling it seems that people recommend getting plumbing inspections every few years for traditional homes, so I’d imagine it’s recommended for apartment buildings as well. But I’m wondering if there is a law that requires it?

Answer (score 4):

NYC local laws are available [here](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/buildings/codes/local-laws.page). There is a new law (152 of 2016) requiring inspection of gas piping systems every 5 years. There is a facade inspection rule (11 of 1998), other rules about elevators. Plumbing must be inspected when installed or modified (part of the permit process) but there is no law requiring periodic inspection of existing plumbing.